# How to compile PHP with ldap support in PHP in a Mac ports Environment?

Tags: ldap, osx-snow-leopard, mac-osx

I had originally installed the LAMP stack using Mac Ports. Another project requires me to enable LDAP support. How do I get about installing it using Mac Ports? My PHP info file has no mention of LDAP.

Since I do not have LDAP, I am getting error in my PHP script like:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo port install php5-ldap`.